# QTableWidget, allow to type numbers only

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qitemdelegate

I have a `QTableWidget` with four columns. I want the user to be able to insert only integers in the first three and a double in the fourth.

I believe that this can be done with delegate, but I have not found relevant examples (only some with `QDateTimeEdit`).

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for [`QItemDelegate`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qitemdelegate.html); it provides a pretty good description on how it can be used.

Since with a delegate, you'll be able to provide your own custom editor, I would suggest that you use a `QLineEdit` with a validator set using [`setValidator()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlineedit.html#setValidator). I believe the classes [`QIntValidator`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qintvalidator.html) and [`QDoubleValidator`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdoublevalidator.html) will be perfect in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. One question only: how do I set the validator for a column? I did it for a QLineEdit, but never for columns.

Comment: The validator is set onto the editor `QLineEdit`. Since the delegate handles creating editors for cells, you can set different delegates for different columns - just use `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn()`.

Comment: I would suggest the possibility of using a spin box and double spin box for the delegate editors instead.  They can still be typed in, already have the validators, and additionally allow the user to quickly increment/decrement the value.